# What does the word NTSTATUS mean?

Tags: wireshark

This is a very basic question; I just ran across the term in the context of a Wireshark capture and I just want to know what the *word* NTSTATUS means.  Every search result I have found explains what different NTSTATUS *codes* indicate; none of them bother to explain what the word NTSTATUS actually refers to.  Also, what does the NT stand for?

Comment: Depending on what the word means this may or may not be on-topic.  But there are a lot of search results here for questions *about* NTSTATUS, so I thought it would be a good place.  Hope someone can help!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"NT" comes from Windows NT, where it originally meant "New Technology".

You're most likely seeing it in Wireshark captures on a Windows network, where the [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) protocol is in use.  Because Microsoft was involved in much of the early development, the common NTSTATUS error codes made their way into the protocol.

Comment: Thanks; the last sentence was especially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may have something to do with the Windows NT Operating system.

I am not 100% sure of this, but here is some information about Windows NT. I had remembered seeing some of the error codes mentioning Windows NT

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT

Windows has never given a formal definition for what the NT stands for but speculation has it that it stands for "New Technology".

See this article for reference: http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/Windows-NT

Answer (score 0):

NT stands for [Windows NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT). NTSTATUS is the error/return type for the Windows NT code base.